# Rename a property name and update all its references accordingly (including in the views)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, refactoring, rename

I'm currently developing C# asp.net MVC applications under visual studio 2012.
The thing is, when I rename a property in a view model using the visual studio refactoring tools, I cannot update ***all*** of its references accordingly, especially those in the `View` pages.

So my question is: Is there any possibility that I can make this process more smooth than just finding them manually and rename each one of them?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately C# is a static language so the compiler can help you catch those kind of errors. The trick is with views, which don't generally get compiled, so you would miss any mistakes there.

However, you simply update the project file, so that the views will be compiled and help you catch errors during compile time.

[Get Compile-Time View Errors in ASP.NET MVC](http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/JonathanTower/j-tower/2013/12/02/get-compile-time-view-errors-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it, but while using Refactoring tools in Visual Studio, I didn't see all the references of the renamed property being renamed inside the Views, so I guess this won't work?

Comment: You are correct, it will not rename them, but at compile time you will be able to catch the errors.

Comment: Actually when I tried it yesterday it didn't complain about compiling errors either. I'll try that again if I get the chance.